# ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer isn't acting concurrent

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to create a multi-threaded listener, but all of the messages execute in the same thread.  When run, the thread ID is always the same, even thought the KafkaListerContainerFactory is (correctly) the one that I instantiated.  If I send 7 messages nearly simultaneously, I would expect the first three to process concurrently, then the next three concurrently, and then the last one.  What I see is that the first processes to completion, then the second, then the third, etc.  Am I misunderstanding something, or just misconfiguring?

This is my listener:

```
@Component
public class ExampleKafkaController {
    Log log = Log.getLog(ExampleKafkaController.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.example.topic}")
    public void listenForMessage(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        log.info("Got record:\n" + record.value());
        System.out.println("Kafka Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println(kafkaListenerContainerFactory);

        log.info("Waiting...");
        waitSleep(10000);

        log.info("Done!");
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${kafka.example.topic}")
    public String topic;    

    public void send(String payload) {
        log.info("sending payload='" + payload + "' to topic='" + topic + "'");
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);
    }

    private void waitSleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my application with the new config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("net.reigrut.internet.services.example.*")
@EntityScan("net.reigrut.internet.services.example.*")
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired 
    ConsumerFactory<Integer,String> consumerFactory;

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        System.out.println("===========>" + consumerFactory);
        System.out.println(factory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Kafka, concurrency is limited to the number of partitions in the topic. If there is only one partition, you will only receive messages on one thread, regardless of the container's concurrency setting.

You should provision the number of partitions to be greater than or equal to the concurrency you desire. If the number of partitions is greater than the concurrency, the partitions will be distributed across the consumer threads.

Only one consumer in a group can consume from a partition.

Comment: Awesome information, I had not gleaned that from any of the documentation.  Thank you!
And just to make sure I understand, but a consumer can consume from more than one partition, but any one partition can only be consumed by a single consumer.  Correct?

Comment: I got the same problem, after checked the config `num.partitions` and also the kafka log dir to confirm my topic has 3 partitions, but i still find it running by single thread(name like `KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#4-1-C-1`), but i the `spring.kafka.listener.concurrency` is `5`, Is there any suggestion for me? thanks very much

Comment: Please don't comment on old questions; ask a new question and show the startup logs related to partition assignment; they are logged at INFO by default by the container.

Comment: This is great, is this behaviour documented somewhere?